# fix an image into place so it follows scrolling up to certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://www.designchemical.com/lab/demo-wordpress-jquery-vertical-mega-menu-plugin.html

The email icon at the corner of the page is the kind of thing that I want.
It is a certain height from the top of the page and follows the page.
I have managed to do this, however when I resize it goes it goes above where I want it to go. 
Here is my code atm:

```
b.remove(), a(this).hasClass("i-am-new") ? a(this).css({ top: (a(window).height()-600) + "px" }) :
            a(this).animate({ top: (a(window).height()) + "px" }, 500), window.innerWidth < 600 && a(this).css({ right: 5 })
```

So what I want it when you resize the window it stops after a certain point. At the moment it finds the height and resizes in that

Comment: I still didnt get what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use position:fixed for your case:

```
.mail{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    right:10px;
    top:50px;
    position:fixed;
    background:white;
}
```

See [full example](http://jsfiddle.net/SdL32/)

Answer (score 1):

Set position to fixed

```
position : fixed;
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqLLw/1/)

I have placed a textbox for the sake of demo .. you may replace it with any control you want to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to stay where it is use css 
    position: absolute;
    float:right;
    top:40px;
    right:0;

This should work, but am on phone so can't test. I'm not sure what you meant by resize though so could be wrong.